# Efficient Random Nodes in XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, random, umbraco, nodes

I need some advice, not being a guru at XSLT...

I have the following code, but the process is slow and results in the page load time being way too long! I know there must be another way, but I can't get my head around it.

Basically, I have a large list of nodes that I'd like to return 3 randomly, without it having to constantly 'for-each' through the entire list every time??

Any help would be greatly appreciated! Thanks.

```
<msxml:script implements-prefix="random" language="C#">
<msxml:assembly name="umbraco"/>
<msxml:using namespace="umbraco"/>
<![CDATA[
public int GetRandom(int minValue, int maxValue)
{
return umbraco.library.GetRandom().Next(minValue, maxValue);
}
]]>
</msxml:script>

 <xsl:template match="/">
   <xsl:variable name="bigCount" select="count(umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(1070)/descendant::* [@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1'][(self::AddANewsStory or self::AddAFeature or self::AddABlogEntry)])" />
   <xsl:for-each select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(1070)//descendant::*[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1'][(self::AddANewsStory or self::AddAFeature or self::AddABlogEntry)]">
     <xsl:sort select="random:GetRandom(1, $bigCount)" order="ascending"/>
        <xsl:if test="position() &lt;= $repeated">
            <div class="relative hover-shadow mb">
              <a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}"><img src="/ImageGen.ashx?image={concat(substring-before(umbracoFile ,'.'),'_Article Image.jpg')}" width="100%" alt="{newsTitle}" /></a>
              <div class="r_content">
                <xsl:variable name="catID" select="umbraco.library:GetXmlNodeById(selectACategory)/@id"/>
                <div class="r_title"><a href="{umbraco.library:NiceUrl(@id)}"><xsl:value-of select="newsTitle"/><xsl:value-of select="blogTitle"/><xsl:value-of select="featureTitle"/></a></div>
              </div>
            </div>
        </xsl:if>
 </xsl:for-each>
 </xsl:template>
```

Comment: Instead of sorting the "large list of nodes" by random, why don't you simply generate three random numbers, then pick the nodes at those three positions?

Comment: That's what I thought, but I just can't seem to get my head round it today (one of those days!). The generated random numbers would need to flexible e.g. 2,3 or 4 etc. Is there an easy way to use an array?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by "flexible". And there are no arrays in XML/XSLT. I am afraid I don't know the first thing about Umbraco but if you like, I can show you how to do this in XSLT (+EXSLT extension function to generate a random number).

Comment: Thanks Michael, I'm going to try this way in the morning. And I just meant that the amount of random numbers to generate would have to be an integer that the user could change in the CMS.

Comment: IMHO, it should be a parameter in a recursive named template. Note also that the template needs to keep track of the numbers already generated, and bump the parameter down only if the random number is new. A simple space-delimited string would be quite sufficient for this purpose.

Comment: This is where my head begins to spin a little with recursive named templates. Something I NEED to get up to speed with.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not sure whether the random script call is what makes it slow, I think it is rather the random number generator in the xsl:sort call that messes up everything.

Try the below script:

Set a variable as a source. Don't use .net calls, they will only slow things down.

```
<xsl:variable name="source" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::@[@level = 1]//*[@isDoc][@id = 1070]"/>
```

Gather your nodes.

```
<xsl:variable name="nodes">
 <xsl:apply-templates select="msxml:node-set($source)//*[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1'][(self::AddANewsStory or self::AddAFeature or self::AddABlogEntry)]" mode=filter"/>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:variable>
```

Get the count from those nodes.

```
<xsl:variable name="bigCount" selet="count(msxml:nodeset($nodes)/*)"/>
```

Identity template, adding a random value as an attribute.
Using the mode attribute to target specific templates: filter.

```
  <xsl:template match="*" mode="filter">    
       <xsl:attribute name="randomOrder">
        <xsl:value-of select="random:GetRandom(1,$bigCount)"/>
       </xsl:attribute>
       <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*"/>
    </xsl:template>
```

Render the nodes.
Using the mode attribute to target specific templates: render.
Sort based on the new attribute randomOrder.

```
<xsl:template match="/">
  <xsl:apply-templates select="msxml:node-set($nodes)/*" mode="render">
     <xsl:sort select="@randomOrder" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
  </xsl:apply-templates>
</xsl:template>
```

Item template to be rendered for each node.

```
<xsl:template match="*" mode="render">
 <div class="relative hover-shadow mb">
  <xsl:value-of select="."/>
 </div>
</xsl:template>
```

And the complete script with the correct namespace added: xmlns:random="urn:my-scripts"

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
        <!DOCTYPE xsl:stylesheet>
        <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
     xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" 
     xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" 
     xmlns:random="urn:my-scripts" version="1.0" 
     exclude-result-prefixes="random msxml umbraco.library">

    <msxml:script implements-prefix="random" language="C#">
    <msxml:assembly name="umbraco"/>
    <msxml:using namespace="umbraco"/>
    <![CDATA[
    public int GetRandom(int minValue, int maxValue)
    {
    return umbraco.library.GetRandom().Next(minValue, maxValue);
    }
    ]]>
    </msxml:script>
         <xsl:param name="currentPage"/>
    <xsl:variable name="source" select="$currentPage/ancestor-or-self::*[@level = 1]//*[@isDoc][@id = 1070]"/>
            <xsl:variable name="nodes">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="msxml:node-set($source)//*[@isDoc and string(umbracoNaviHide) != '1'][(self::AddANewsStory or self::AddAFeature or self::AddABlogEntry)]" mode="filter"/>
            </xsl:variable>
            <xsl:variable name="bigCount" select="count(msxml:node-set($nodes)/*)"/>
            <xsl:template match="*" mode="filter">
                <xsl:attribute name="randomOrder">
                    <xsl:value-of select="random:GetRandom(1,$bigCount)"/>
                </xsl:attribute>
                <xsl:copy-of select="node()|@*"/>
            </xsl:template>
            <xsl:template match="/">
                <xsl:apply-templates select="msxml:node-set($nodes)/*" mode="render">
                    <xsl:sort select="@randomOrder" data-type="number" order="ascending"/>
                </xsl:apply-templates>
            </xsl:template>
            <xsl:template match="*" mode="render">
                <div class="relative hover-shadow mb">
                    <xsl:value-of select="."/>
                </div>
            </xsl:template>
        </xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Many thanks for the reply!  Although I'm still having issues adding the code to Umbraco. Firstly I'm getting the following error on the line;

        `<msxml:script implements-prefix="random" language="C#">`

Secondly, I can't for the life of me get the script to work to test as I constantly receive the error;

       `Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt'.`

I'm using Umbraco 4.7.1.1 if that helps?

Comment: You have to define the namespace in the xsl:stylesheet element: <xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:msxml="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt" xmlns:umbraco.library="urn:umbraco.library" version="1.0" exclude-result-prefixes="msxml umbraco.library">

Comment: Updated the code, added the namespace for the random script xmlns:random="urn:my-scripts"

Comment: I have and I'm still receiving the same error. I'm beginning to wonder if it needs updating? I'm going to have another go at it in the morning and possibly try generating the positions first and then simply displaying the chosen ones. Thanks for you help. I maybe back!

Comment: Same error with updated code!? `System.Xml.Xsl.XslTransformException: Cannot find a script or an extension object associated with namespace 'urn:schemas-microsoft-com:xslt'.`

Comment: Found the error in the bigCount variable: nodeset should be node-set

Comment: Error free! :) Just need to get it display something now, as it's not bringing anything back. Just need to figure out if it's an issue in the filter or node selection. Thanks again!

Comment: Please mark the answer as the solution if it answers your question.Thanks!